# MouseLeaveでListBoxを非表示にすることができない

Tags: c#, windows

お世話になります。

マウスのEnterで表示され、Leaveで非表示になるListBoxを作ろうとしています。

背面にPanelを敷き、その上にListBoxを配置して、PanelのMouseEnterでListBoxを表示、MouseLeaveで非表示にしようとしているのですが、うまく非表示になってくれません。

ListBoxではなく、他のFlowLayoutPanelなどでは正しく動作するのですが、ListBoxの時にはうまく動きません。

かと思いきや、ListBoxのMouseLeaveの中の処理にブレイクポイントをかけると正しく処理も走るし、その後非表示になるのですが、ブレイクポイントを外して普通に動作させるとうまくいかないのです。

以下がそのコードです。(VisualStudioExpress2015)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace A
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBox1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBox1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
namespace A
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 253);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.panel1.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.panel1_MouseEnter);
            // 
            // listBox1
            // 
            this.listBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox1.ItemHeight = 15;
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.ScrollAlwaysVisible = true;
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 253);
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.listBox1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_MouseLeave);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 253);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
    }
}
```

尚、PanelとListBoxのMarginとPaddingはすべて0で、隙間なくぴったり配置しています。
PanelはDock.Left、ListBoxはDock.Fillです。

原因と対策をご教授ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

ご提示のソースだとlistBox1_MouseLeaveイベントの直後にpanel1_MouseEnterイベントが走ってしまい、結果的にlistBox1のVisibleは変更されないでしょう。

イベントを以下の2種類とすることで期待の結果となるのではないでしょうか。

```
private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.listBox1.Visible = true;
}

private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.listBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ですが、本文にもあるように、PanelはListBoxですっぽり隠れており、ListBoxのMouseLeaveが走るときには、PanelのMouseEnterは走らないはずなのですが…。

Comment: ご提示のソースだと、ListBoxのMouseLeaveが走った時点でListBoxがVisible=falseとなり、
即座にPanelにマウスカーソルが当たりP‌​anelのMouseEnterが走っているものと思います。
ですので、見た目上はlistBox1からマウスカーソルを外しても
listBox1は表示されたままとなります。
ブレイクポイントで止めると正しく動作するのは、
デバッグしている最中にマウスカーソルがPanelから外れているからです。

Comment: そうでしょぅか…。ListBoxのMouseLeaveが走った時点で、Panelからもマウスは
外に出ているはずです。Size(100, 253);とあるように、サイズはぴったりだから、
EnterとLeaveのメソッドは同時には走らないのですが…。後、いただきましたサンプルですと、フォームの外に出れば消えますが、フォーム内にいる間は表示されたままになっています。やはりこれだと思ったような動作にはなりません。更に、ListBox以外ではうまくいくのも解らないのですが…。

Comment: 結局、問題は解決しないままでした。
引き続きお解りになる方の回答をお待ちします。

Answer (score 0):

綺麗な書き方ではないですが希望の動作にはなるかと思います。

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.listBox1.Visible = false;
    }

    const int INTERVAL = 100;
    int lastLeavedTickCount = 0;

    private void listBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.lastLeavedTickCount = System.Environment.TickCount;
        this.listBox1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (lastLeavedTickCount + INTERVAL > System.Environment.TickCount)
            return;
        this.listBox1.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

マウスの速度によってListBoxのMouseLeave時にPanelのMouseEnterが発生したりしなかったりなので無理矢理ですね･･･。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
すみません、ずっと気がつきませんでした。
いただいたソースですが、やはり無理やりですよね…。
もう少しエレガントにできればよいのですが…。

Comment: ListBoxのMouseLeaveの処理が確実に動くのであれば Visible = false 後に Refresh() を試す価値はありそうですね。
なお VS Community 2019 では ListBoxのMouseLeaveの処理にブレイクポイントをかけても break しませんでした。